# problem regarding maximum pool size in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-pooling

I have been working on a small file manager module in a project where a list of folders are shown in a treeview. I have done the whole thing in javascript. Everytime I click a node, a list of data is fetched into a datareader and populated in the front end. 
But when I deploy the application in IIS, after about 18 subsequent clicks, the IIS is halted and I have to reset it again. When I checked the event viewer  I got the following error

> Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
>       Exception message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

So in my connection string in the web.config, I set pooling to True and max pool size to 200 and the problem was solved.

But I wonder is it a good practice to use connection pool size in this way. Or how do we prevent so many connections from being opened.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you don't free up unused resources. More specifically, you absolutely must call `Dispose()` on all database-related objects, like `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataReader`, etc. Or, better yet, wrap them in `using` statements.

Comment: actually i m closing the connection. In the datareader  i m explicitly calling reader.Close(), is Dispose() method necessary?

Answer (score 1):

A sample connection string for SQL Server:

```
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=pubs;User ID=sa;Password=;Max Pool Size=75;Min Pool Size=5;"
```

Do like this may help You:)

Default value of Max Pool size is 100.
You can set it to a higher number also so far as performance of the server is not a issue..

Comment: thnks dude! but thts the problem, max pool size of 100 is still getting less, what happens when the no of users grow?